# How to group by based on value in json using jq?

Tags: json, linux, group-by, jq

I have the following json

```
[
      {
        "certname": "server1",
        "environment": "production",
        "name": "memorysize",
        "value": "62.76 GiB"
      },
      {
        "certname": "server1",
        "environment": "production",
        "name": "processorcount",
        "value": 12
      },
      {
        "certname": "server2",
        "environment": "production",
        "name": "memorysize",
        "value": "62.76 GiB"
      },
      {
        "certname": "server2",
        "environment": "production",
        "name": "processorcount",
        "value": 10
      }
    ]
```

And I want to convert to this format where it's grouped by the certname. The challenge is I need to use value for to make it as the key as follow

```
    [
      {
        "certname": "server1",
        "memorysize": "62.76 GiB",
        "processorcount": 12
      },
      {
        "certname": "server2",
        "memorysize": "62.76 GiB",
        "processorcount": 10
      }
    ]
```

How do I do this using jq? I have tried to_entries but it doesn't help either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a commented jq script. Feel free to use it as is, or strip out the newlines and comments and use it as is.

```
# First, we construct an object that maps each `$certname` to `{certname: $certname}`. We name it $init.

(map({key:.certname, value: {certname}}) | unique | from_entries) as $init |

# Next, we take each object of the input in turn (name it $attr) and assign its
# `name:value` into one of the objects.
# $init is the dictionary above
# Reduce will pass the current dictionary as . for each invocation, and the assignment
# returns the input object.

reduce .[] as $attr ($init; .[$attr.certname][$attr.name] = $attr.value) |

# Our initial dictionary has now been expanded with attributes.
# Map it back to an array of objects. .[] is a stream of objects,
# we capture that in an outer array.

[.[]]
```

Comment: Thank you this works really well. Thank you for the explanation as well.

Comment: How do you change certname to hostname in the output?

Comment: This is what I have so far `[(map({key:.certname, value: {certname}}) | unique | from_entries) as $init |reduce .[] as $attr ($init; .[$attr.certname][$attr.name] = $attr.value)| .[]| .["hostname"] = .certname |del(.certname)]` but I was looking if there is a better solution.

Comment: `{certname}` is short for `{certname: .certname}`, so change that to `{hostname: .certname}`

Comment: Thank you again.